# Accessing Nested JSON string in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON string below and decode it PHP array using

```
json_decode($jsonTwo,true);

$jsonTwo = '{
  "techID": "5",
  "payment":[
    {"amount":"9.5","reference":"102"},
    {"amount":"10","reference":"103"}
  ]
 }';
```

How can I use the foreach loop to access the "payment" array?

Comment: You don't need to use a loop after you decode that string. Just access it like `$decoded['payment'];`

Comment: You can see that payment is an array (square brackets), so after json_decode (which should be AFTER you declare the variable) you can just do foreach ($jsonTwo['payment'] as $payment) { print_r($payment); }

Answer (score 0):

```
$decodedJson = json_decode($jsonTwo, true);

foreach ($decodedJson["payment"] as $payment){
  // Your logic
}
```

If you ommit the second parameter in `json_decode`, `$decodedJson` is a `StdClass`, as said in: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php